# How to create script to turn excel table rows into HTML pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, excel

I have an excel table that contains address of local businesses along with a small description. Need to upload this directory to my Wordpress site.

I want every row in the table to be a separate HTML webpage. I have a css template to style the content, but the table has over 1000 entries. Therefore, doing it manually would be a pain.

ps. If there is a word press plugin I could use that would be most convenient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code needs C1, C2, ..., Cx, etc in CSS.

```
Dim sDir As String
Dim iRnd, iCnd, iRow, iCol As Integer
Dim oFso As Object
Dim oFil As Object

sDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
iRnd = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
iCnd = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For iRow = 1 To iRnd

    Set oFil = oFso.CreateTextFile(sDir & iRow & ".html")
    oFil.WriteLine "<html><body>"
    For iCol = 1 To iCnd
        oFil.WriteLine "<div class='C" & iCol & "'>" & Cells(iRow, iCol) & "</div>"
    Next
    oFil.WriteLine "</body></html>"
    oFil.Close

Next

Set oFil = Nothing
Set oFso = Nothing

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Sorry for sounding like a goof, but what language is this in? Im unfamiliar with it.

Comment: This code is in Visual Basic for Applications, which is available from within Excel.